# As of Feb 2016, how big is the ethereum blockchain size and its monthly growth rate?

Tags: blockchain, storage

As of Feb 2016, how big is the ethereum blockchain size and its monthly growth rate? Does the blockchain implement anything with pruning to reduce its size in the near future?