# How big is the Ethereum blockchain now (May 2016)? And what is it expected to be in the future?

Tags: blockchain

How big is the Ethereum blockchain now (May 2016)? And what size is it expected to be in the future?

- a) Now
- b) One month from now
- c) Two months from now
- d) One year from now

Comment: And, [As of Feb 2016, how big is the ethereum blockchain size and its monthly growth rate?](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/798/87)